# Is Light Egg Nog supposed to drink directly without cooking?

Tags: eggs, milk

Is Light Egg Nog supposed to drink directly without cooking? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do not cook store-bought eggnog.

Comment: I definitely don’t cook it, but I often thin it out with some milk (*cough* and some liquor).

Comment: I drink a whole package in the picture,  because it just expired. it tastes like sugar and I don't feel very comfortable. Is it healthy?

Comment: .....I..... 32 ounces is more eggnog than one would normally drink in a single serving.

Comment: Oh buddy. That’s thousands of calories of dairy and sugar. That would make anybody sick.

Comment: I drink 6 ounces or so at a time.

Comment: @Preston, the stuff tastes like glue if not diluted *properly*.